# Combo Indicator LED / Fuel Pump Relay Kill Switch

Tags: led, switches, relay, automotive, dpdt

I'm looking to wire up simple on/on DPDT switch in my car so that in one position, power is cut to the fuel pump relay and power is sent to a fake alarm LED, and in the other position the fuel relay is enabled and the LED is disabled.

My plan is to connect the fuel pump wire to terminals 1 and 3 and the LED to terminals 4 and 6, but do I need to connect terminals 2 and 5 to anything for this to be safe/functional? For that matter, is it preferred to connect the loads and supplies to specific terminals or are they interchangeable?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my English.

[image: Spec sheet]

Comment: We can't see your switch so we don't know which terminal is which. Post a photo or, better, a link to the datasheet.

Comment: Thank @Transistor, added spec sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would connect the fuel pump power source to terminal 5, and the pump to terminal 6.

Connect permanent 12 V (not controlled by the ignition switch) to terminal 2, and the LED + terminal to terminal 1.  The LED - terminal is connected to Ground.

Terminals 3 and 4 would not be used.

Answer (score 0):

No that would not work as you want to wire them. You need to wire them with the center common pins in mind. And alternate between one side and the other.

The power to the relay you want to cut and the switch in between. You can do one side ( the 12v power) to 2 and the relay side to 1.

Now for your led, assuming it has a resistor already or Its a module, then you can wire 12V power to pin 5 and the led power side to pin 6.

You could use the same 12v power wire for 2 and 5, but since the fuel pump relay is likely a switched power source (not always on) the led would only be on when the car is on. If you wire the led side to an always on 12v source, you need to make sure it's not going to drain your car battery.